# how to get the value of the clicked table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

My question is: how do I get the value of the clicked row and column?

The code I have is this:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: json,
        success: function(data) {
            var response_array = JSON.parse(data);
            var columns = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'telephone', 'website', 'city'];
            var table_html = ' <tr>\n' +
                '<th id="id">Id</th>\n' +
                '<th id="name">Bedrijfnaam</th>\n' +
                '<th id="email">E-mail</th>\n' +
                '<th id="telephone">Telefoon</th>\n' +
                '<th id="website">Website</th>\n' +
                '<th id="city">Plaats</th>\n' +
                '</tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < response_array.length; i++) {
                //create html table row
                table_html += '<tr>';
                for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                    //create html table cell, add class to cells to identify columns
                    table_html += '<td class="' + columns[j] + '" >' + response_array[i][columns[j]] + '</td>'
                }
                table_html += '</tr>'
            };
            $("#posts").append(table_html);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); }
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="tabel">
     <table id="posts">
     </table>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
 $('#posts').click(function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        var id = $("tr").find(".id").html();
        console.log(id);
});
```

Sadly this will only give me the id of the first row, no matter where I click.

Any help is appreciated!

Ramon

Comment: Go read up on how to use `$(this)` in jQuery ...

Comment: I tried $(this) if that is what you mean, but with the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below approach should be able to find the ID

```
$('#post').on('click', function(e){
var id = $(e.target).closest('tr').find(".id").html();
console.log(id)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! will accept this answer when i can

Answer (score 0):

HTML content of clicked row

```
 $('#posts tr').click(function(){
       $(this).html();
 });
```

text from clicked td

```
 $('#posts tr td').click(function(){
        $(this).text();
 });
```

If you are using **ajax** and  you are **redrawing elements**, you will not catch em via click function. You will need to add on function:

```
$(document).on('click','#posts tr td','function(){
      $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use AddEventListener for your table, it will work for sure.
Like this:

```
let posts = document.getlementById('posts');
posts.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
// anything you need here, for example:
console.log(e.target);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

As well - it will be fine not to use same IDs for elements in a grid (like id="id" which you have), it should be different.

Comment: why does it matter when i use the same ids for elements in this case? with the selector i will get unique ids anyways right?

Comment: Yes, Ramon, for your case of question it doesn't matter - it was just a notice. But according to question - using event listeners allows you to 'listen' for needed DOM events doesn't matter where did it come from - ajax or initial DOM load

Comment: Okay then I understand :)

Comment: Hope it was useful for you.